# autonomously localise robot at "starting" point

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I need a little clarification for the localisation methods for the following purpose:

- I want to autonomously localise my Turtlebot at the starting point (which could be anywhere in a room) then send some navigation goals for it to follow, then at the end i want my turtlebot to return to the same initial point which it had localised itself in the beginning, all without any user intervention.

my setup is a Turtlebot, Hokuyo Lidar, ROS indigo and without initial map (i'd want to create the map on the fly).  as i am still learning ROS, im wondering what components can provide a solution for this task in order to localise the robot in the start and save the pose for later use?

**UPDATE:** with which `functions` i could set and retrieve the initial pose?

Thanks a lot for the inputs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206280/autonomously-localise-robot-at-%22starting%22-point/) by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueberrycheesecake2019](https://answers.ros.org/users/44641/blueberrycheesecake2019/) on 2019-08-09**:
Hello,
I am trying to do the same thing. Could you help me out regarding the steps I must follow?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[slam_gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping) is a SLAM implementation that is often used with ROS.

You can start with [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM) to show how to use it with a Turtlebot.

---

Originally posted by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) with karma: 521 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-03-30**:
An alternative to gmapping is [hector_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam)

But @Morgan is right - you need to have a SLAM node that will take your initial position, mark it in the map and expand out from there. You can then send navigation goals anywhere wrt to this building/built map.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-03-30**:
@Morgan , @2ROS0 worked with gmapping this much.. is there a specific function or service that i should call to give me the initial position for the robot before it even moved? wud those first laser readings really help the localisation here w/o a map built yet? or shld do an out n back to get info?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-03-31**:
That's one of the requirements for a SLAM algorithm - to give you an initial position "even before it moved" and build from there so you don't need to give it anything like that. Yes, it will use the first laser readings to seed localization.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-03-31**:
@2ROS0 thank you, so how do i do it in practice since i want it to be autonomous, i mean how do i call or get the initial pose in order to use it later (i.e. as the final move_base goal). or is it always (0,0)?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-03-31**:
When you don't have a map, there is no initial pose. You can look at it like it will always start at (0, 0). Once you have the map, you can set initial pose in that map that could be the place your robot always starts in. The robot could alternatively autonomously localize in the map to get pose.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-03-31**:
@2ROS0 thanks so much for the replies. so just to round it up for myself, when it start from scratch for gmapping i set the initial pose to (0,0) and then it builds the map around it. then when it gets the nav command to go to (0,0) it will return to point 1? thanks again :)